# How to bundle a library inside another library in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-library, aar

So, basically I have multiple modules say Module A, B, C
App dependes on Module A

Module A depends on Module B & C.

While generating the aar or publishing the aar, I don't want users to import Module B & C. They should just import Module A and automatically they should get access to B & C as well.
How can I achieve the same?

THIS IS WHAT I HAVE TRIED
I created a simple project and added 2 modules A and B.

I included the dependency of Module B in Module A. And Module A was used in app module.

Then I ran command of gradle assemble -> it generate aar for me. I used Module B's aar and placed inside libs of Module A. And updated the path of build.gradle to use aar instead of project B.
When I tried to run gradle assemble again - it gave below error -

Direct local .aar file dependencies are not supported when building an AAR. The resulting AAR would be broken because the classes and Android resources from any local .aar file dependencies would not be packaged in the resulting AAR. Previous versions of the Android Gradle Plugin produce broken AARs in this case too (despite not throwing this error).

Comment: Any success with this? I'm facing the same problem now!

Answer (score -1):

In main libraryA use other libraryB with `api` eg.

```
dependencies {
    api project(':libraryB')
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works only, when that libraryA is used as project inside another app.
But my usecase is - that I want to create an aar which has both module code base (libraryA and libraryB) then that aar can be used inside any app.